# Modeling constraints in Z3 and Unsat core cases

Tags: c#, z3, smt

I am using the Z3 solver and implementing in C#. I have used the example given by Microsoft in the description of their .Net API (http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/dotnet/Program.cs). In this example I have tried to replace the model in function "UnsatCoreAndProofExample" with my own model which is:

```
Expr x = ctx.MkConst("x", ctx.MkIntSort());
Expr y = ctx.MkConst("y", ctx.MkIntSort());
Expr zero = ctx.MkNumeral(0, ctx.MkIntSort());
Expr one = ctx.MkNumeral(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
Expr five = ctx.MkNumeral(5, ctx.MkIntSort());

BoolExpr constraint1 = ctx.MkBoolConst("Constraint1");
solver.AssertAndTrack(ctx.MkGt((ArithExpr)x, (ArithExpr)zero), constraint1);
BoolExpr constraint2 = ctx.MkBoolConst("Constraint2");
solver.AssertAndTrack(ctx.MkEq((ArithExpr)y, ctx.MkAdd((ArithExpr)x, (ArithExpr)one)), constraint2);
BoolExpr constraint3 = ctx.MkBoolConst("Constraint3");
solver.AssertAndTrack(ctx.MkLt((ArithExpr)y, (ArithExpr)five), constraint3);
BoolExpr constraint4 = ctx.MkBoolConst("Constraint4");
solver.AssertAndTrack(ctx.MkLt((ArithExpr)x, (ArithExpr)zero), constraint4);

Status result = solver.Check();
```

The result which I am expecting is to say that Constraint1 and Constraint4 are returned in the Unsat Code. I know that the setting for returning the Unsatcore are correct because when I run the original "UnsatCoreAndProofExample" function the unsat Core is returned. But when I JUST change the model to the model above although the result is Unsat but no Unsatcore is returned. 
So my question is, could it be because of the way I am writing my model or is there another mistake I am making?

Comment: This looks like somewhere along the line there's a bug, we're working on it.

Answer (score 2):

There was indeed a bug in the infrastructure which made it very hard to use AssertAndTrack correctly. This is now fixed in the unstable branch (fix is [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/9b137d54d34e0a014b4c5c5c9c21cbf43b78f604)). I've also added another example to the .NET and Java examples that uses AssertAndTrack to get a core.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph! This was a great help!